# Preventing JSF/PrimeFaces URLs from appearing in search engine results

Tags: java, url, primefaces, robots.txt, x-robots-tag

I'm working on a web application built using JavaServer Faces (JSF) with the PrimeFaces framework. In our deployment process, when I upload an archive to Jenkins, it generates two different links, each attached to a separate database. One link points to our homologation server for testing purposes, while the other points to our production server for user access.

My primary concern is that I want to prevent the URLs of the homologation server, which is used exclusively for testing, from appearing in search engine results, especially Google. I've tried using robots.txt with noindex, but it seems that these URLs are still indexed by Google.

Are there specific considerations or configurations related to JSF and PrimeFaces that I should be aware of when attempting to exclude these URLs from search engine indexing? Is there a recommended approach or best practice for achieving this?

tried using the meta tag to validate the URL in Java, but I didn't receive any validation. I'm currently waiting to see if it will disappear from the search results, but it seems to make no difference. I really don't want to use the archive because I fear I can't control whether it's the homologation URL or not. However, I am completely open to ideas.

Comment: You should password protect any URLs you don't want to show up in search engines or protect them behind a firewall.

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: It depends.  What web server, proxy server, and/or CDN are you using?  It is often easier to add basic password protection at some level above your web app.  There may even be a way to do it within JSF, but I have no experience with it.